# New azure devops pipeline in existing repository has many related workitems

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines

### Background

This happens in existing repositories. We decided to switch to new pipelines based on multi stage yaml pipelines, while previously only the build was in yaml and the releases were done using the classis release pipelines

### Issue

Whenever a new pipeline is created in one of these repositories, on the first run, many workitems created and closed in the past few years are linked to the run. These items date back for years and interfere with our auditing system. Once the pipeline is deployed to all stages, this behavior stops. So if afterwards a new PR is submitted and a new run start only the workitem that was linked through the PR is now in the run's related workitems.

### Done

I've checked the "Automatically link work items included in this run" option but it is turned off, which is what I would expect as these are new pipelines. Just to be sure I also checked this setting for the old pipelines and they have this setting turned off as well.
I also looked around in the project and organization settings but couldn't find anything related.

### Question

I have two questions:

1. What causes this behavior?
2. Can this behavior be turned off so that new pipelines only have the workitem related that is linked on the PR?

Please let me know if anything is unclear of if additional information is needed.